# How to pass the computer's Name/HostName to Web Api endpoint using cUrl

Tags: curl, .net-core

I have a Web Api application created using .net core.

When I use the curl as below, it works fine if I give my hostname instead of ABCD.

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:14121/api/SetValue?hostName=ABCD&status=false" -H "accept: application/json" -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

But if I run the curl on a different computer I want to access that computers hostname and add that to curl.

Is there something like the below to do it?

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:14121/api/SetValue?hostName=gethostname()&status=false" -H "accept: application/json" -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your command using bash you can use the variable `$HOSTNAME`:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:14121/api/SetValue?hostName=$HOSTNAME&status=false" -H "accept: application/json" -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

And replace `localhost` with the real server address.

For windows replace `$HOSTNAME` with `%COMPUTERNAME%`:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:14121/api/SetValue?hostName=%COMPUTERNAME%&status=false" -H "accept: application/json" -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

Comment: @Stephene, is there a way to do it in the cmd.exe with curl rather than going for bash. I have not used bash so do not have a clear idea. I want to use this curl in different platforms(windows/mac/linux).